# Month and Year picker in Material UI React

Tags: reactjs, date, datetime, material-ui, mui-x

Is there any way to implement a month Picker and year picker using Material UI.
In month view the output should be like only month and the year only Eg:- 2020-09

Comment: Have you tried https://material-ui.com/components/pickers/ ?

Comment: Yeah i tried, in there we can get the whole date only. what i want is to render only the month and year (not the date of month)list and retrive the month and year. Is there any way

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Material UI V5**

Material UI v5 added the `DatePicker` to `@mui/lab` so you don't need to install the third-party package anymore. To restrict to month and year only, you can set the [`view` prop](https://mui.com/components/date-picker/#views-playground) like this:

```
<DatePicker
  views={['year', 'month']}
  label="Year and Month"
  minDate={new Date('2012-03-01')}
  maxDate={new Date('2023-06-01')}
  value={value}
  onChange={setValue}
  renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} helperText={null} />}
/>
```

> output should be like only month and the year only Eg:- 2020-09

To change how the `TextField` display the current date, use `inputFormat` prop. If you're using date-fns, see [this](https://date-fns.org/v2.25.0/docs/format) table here for reference.

```
<DatePicker inputFormat="yyyy-MM"
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

**Material UI V4**

You can use different views as demonstrated in this section [here](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/demo/datepicker#different-views).

```js
<DatePicker
  variant="inline"
  openTo="year"
  views={["year", "month"]}
  label="Year and Month"
  helperText="Start from year selection"
  value={selectedDate}
  onChange={handleDateChange}
/>
```

#### Live Demo

[image: Edit 64112889/month-and-year-picker-in-materialui-react-js]

Answer (score 7):

In your component, pass an array called `views` with `month` and `year`.

```js
views={["year", "month"]}
```

Take a look at `views` prop for more info: https://material-ui-pickers.dev/api/KeyboardDatePicker

Also change the `format` to `MM/yyyy`

```js
format="MM/yyyy"
```

Here is a sandbox for your reference:

[image: month-and-year-picker-in-materialui-react-js-by-ankit-beniwal]

Answer (score 2):

```
import "date-fns";
import React from "react";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import DateFnsUtils from "@date-io/date-fns";
import { MuiPickersUtilsProvider, DatePicker } from "@material-ui/pickers";

export default function MaterialUIPickers() {
  // The first commit of Material-UI
  const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = React.useState<Date | null>(
    new Date("2014-08-18T21:11:54")
  );

  const handleDateChange = (date: Date | null) => {
    setSelectedDate(date);
  };

  return (
    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
      <Grid container justify="space-around">
<DatePicker
  variant="inline"
  openTo="year"
  views={["year", "month"]}
  label="Year and Month"
  helperText="Start from year selection"
  value={selectedDate}
  onChange={handleDateChange}
/>
      </Grid>
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
  );
}
```

Second Solution

```
import "date-fns";
import React from "react";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import DateFnsUtils from "@date-io/date-fns";
import {
  MuiPickersUtilsProvider,
  KeyboardDatePicker
} from "@material-ui/pickers";

export default function MaterialUIPickers() {
  const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = React.useState(
    new Date("2014-08-18T21:11:54")
  );

  const handleDateChange = (date) => {
    setSelectedDate(date);
  };

  return (
    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
      <Grid container justify="space-around">
        <KeyboardDatePicker
          disableToolbar
          variant="inline"
          format="MM/yyyy"
          views={["year", "month"]}
          margin="normal"
          id="date-picker-inline"
          label="Date picker inline"
          value={selectedDate}
          onChange={handleDateChange}
          KeyboardButtonProps={{
            "aria-label": "change date"
          }}
        />
      </Grid>
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).